# Get the total number of rows pertaining to particular id, and also get the presence of particular value in a column - MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have a users table with three columns -> user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, username VARCHAR(256), email VARCHAR(100), country VARCHAR(50).

I run this query -> `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE country = 'Brazil'`.

This gets me the total number of users from brazil. But i would also like to get to know about the presence of a particular user_id in the returned rows.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, SUM(IF(user_id=XXX, 1, 0)) AS xxx_is_present
...
```

if xxx is present in the underlying result set, the sum will be `> 0`

Comment: Now when I do this -> `SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, SUM(IF user_id='1', 1, 0) AS present FROM users WHERE country = 'Brazil'`

It shows an error

Comment: I had a typo in my answer. forgot brackets for the IF() function.

Comment: can you please tell, how do i calculate the time taken to get this result.

Comment: get the time before/after you do the query call?